# When I export my functions, types are lost - Typescript

Tags: typescript

**Main Problem**

I am using es6 modules to import and export files.
There's one file where I import some functions to export them again using alias. I do it using:

`export { default as aliasname } from './path/to/file';`

Nice! It's all fine, except that when I import some of these alias functions and hover the mouse over them using VSCode, I don't see any types defined. I can use the functions, but the types were lost.

I am using Typescript 4.2.4.

**Additional Info:**

There are two directories. 
One with the file that I am using to import the alias functions. 
And another with the file exporting the alias functions, the files with these functions definitions, and a global.d.ts file with the types.

Comment: The `export...from` statement normally does carry across type information, but a separate `global.d.ts` seems odd here; are some of the files involved plain JS? Could you provide a more complete minimal example, with a simplified snippet of one of the original function definitions, its declaration in `global.d.ts` and its import in the other directory?

Comment: I am really laughing out loud now! Thanks for your help! I committed a silly mistake. I was importing the compiled file that exports the alias functions, so it was a .js file. Now I changed it and imported the original .ts file. It works! Thanks to your comment, I reproduced the situation in a new directory and saw it worked just fine! Then I compared to see what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I committed a silly mistake.

**I was importing the compiled file that exports the alias functions, so it was a .js file. Now I changed it and imported the original .ts file. It works!**